# Lightning and classic experience sharing in one development environment

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce-classic, app-development, lightning-development

In my team we are all working using a single development environment. So, when one needs to go to Salesforce Classic and one needs to work in Lightning Experience we are getting a little bit of conflict and confusion.

So, my question is what is the correct approach to developing an app for Salesforce in team?

I mean is there a way to have a different versions of environment for everyone and then merge them together once the development of a feature is done?

Thank you.

I hope my question is clear, and in case it is not, please, ask me to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, my question is what is the correct approach to developing an app for Salesforce in team?

In good old days, we used Developer sandboxes for developers, either same or individual and then migrate the changes to upper environments.

But now we have **[Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_intro.htm)**.

> I mean is there a way to have a different versions of environment for everyone and then merge them together once the development of a feature is done?

**Yes**. Using [**Scratch Orgs**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) you will be able to solve what you are looking for.

> The scratch org is a source-driven and disposable deployment of Salesforce code and metadata. A scratch org is fully configurable, allowing developers to emulate different Salesforce editions with different features and preferences.

Refer to the documentation and **[trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/sfdx_get_started)** on this topic for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In a team every developer has its own user and its own landing page and other configurations.

In fact, every developer could have its own sandbox.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a source there I would be able to read about this?

Comment: @RamonLoureiro - you would need to expand on this as the number of sandboxes available depends on the edition so depending on the size of the developer team, you may not have 1 sandbox per developer.

Comment: Yes, sorry.. not always is possible to have as much sanboxes as you want...
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model/sfdx_dev_model_release